# Unable to create post request from Nuxt.js to ml model hosted on flask server "http://127.0.0.1:5000" and extract data

Tags: flask, axios, nuxt.js

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pACAn.png)

Unable to post data using axios in nuxt.js to ml model working on flask link.

Comment: What is not working here exactly? Did you checked your server or network requests? Also, please do not post code as images but rather actual text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.